# When connecting to someones wifi without using it, can they see search history from the past?

Tags: network, wifi, phone

We visited a friend who's working as a programmer. He told me to connect my phone to his wifi so he could send me a picture, however he didn't send it and I left my phone connected to his wifi for an hour without using it.

Can he see my search history, notes, pictures, messages, passwords? Or install a spyware in my phone? Just via wifi even if i didn't use it to open anything?

Comment: highly unlikely if you are using updated phone with good password and he didn't have have unrestricted physical access to the phone

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that it is highly unlikely that your device was compromised by your friend in the way you describe.

A much more likely way to exploit this situation would be to monitor your web traffic **while connected**. Doing this might allow him to see what types of websites you are going to **while you are connected to his wifi**, but usually won't allow him to see the contents of those websites or passwords you used to connect to different online services. He also would not be able to install spyware, see the contents of your phone, or view your web history simply by monitoring your traffic in this way.

Although the compromise you described is *possible*, I think it is very unlikely that your friend has that capability. You might expect a government or a highly advanced penetration-testing team to have the capability you described. Either that or your phone is very, very, very out-of-date

Comment: Well I think he's very capable but I didn't open anything while connecting to his wifi. Thank you so much for answering. I'm willing to see if anyone has another opinion too.